# Number's a word, a word's a number!

Tags: word, wordplay

Without you, I connect, and create purpose. 
But if you add five we can go golfing! 
As I grow older without you, I have to hunt for my dinner. 
But this, the one I am, is the only of its kind.

**The answer is a single word**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Partial answer) I think you are

> **Four**

*Without you, I connect, and create purpose.*

> Remove the letter U and get "for", which is a conjunction that indicates a goal or purpose.

*But if you add five we can go golfing!*

> "For" + "e" (the 5th letter in the English alphabet) = "fore". The expression ["Fore!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore_(golf)) may be shouted during golf, to warn bystanders of fast-moving golf balls.

*As I grow older without you, I have to hunt for my dinner.*

> "For" + "age" = "Forage". Foraging means hunting or searching for food.

*But this, the one I am, is the only of its kind.*

> (Credit to [@BusinessCat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22168/business-cat)) "Four" has 4 letters. It is the only integer with a value equal to the number of letters in its name.

Comment: For the last part: maybe a stretch but four is the only the number that has the same number of letters in the word as its own value.

Comment: @BusinessCat Thanks, that may be the answer!

Comment: Front nine is a good reference, but not the intended association with Golf. "Big Five" is also not right. You will want [tag:wordplay].

Comment: Third maybe rot13 sbentr(e)